# Facebook, setReadPermissions and setPublishPermissions

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

Hey I'm trying to use two different type of permissions.

When I'm using only one, all works fine.

But when I'm using both of them the app crashes:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("friends_games_activity"));
authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

How can I add the 2 permissions (`friends_games_activity` and `publish_actions`) without problems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot have both permissions in SDK 3.0, you need separate them. You can first open session for read, get what you want and then openForPublish.

> Note: In the new SDK, you may ask only for read permissions when you
>   first open a session. You should not prompt your user for publish
>   permissions until the time at which they are actually publishing an
>   action to Facebook. This increases user trust, and also the likelihood
>   that your user will choose to publish stories from your app. To
>   request further permissions, use Session.openForRead or
>   Session.openForPublish.

You need to call clearPermissions. It's described here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton/#setReadPermissions(List)

Comment: thank you, but how can I clear the permission or re-setup the new one?

I set them on the Button "authButton " not the session
can I do:?
authButton.clearPermissions();
  authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

Comment: 1.authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("friends_games_activity"));
2. when press button you get read permissions
3. clearPermissions();
4. authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
5. when press you get write permissions

Comment: ok. but the authButton is the LogIn to facebook button
and I would like that when I press for example.
Send Score button the permission will be fliiped

Comment: Yes, permissions will be flipped. When user is logged in, you dont need read permissions.

Comment: i have same problem but fbloginbtn not adding the publish_actions so please tell me how can i achieve @Marcin Gawel